# Validating input and getline() function

Tags: c++, validation, io, getline

So I want to validate the user only enters text and not numbers. If any number is input, then I ask her again for input. I thought this would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name = "";

    cout << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    while (!cin) // or cin.fail()
    {
        cout << "Numbers are not allowed, input name again: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); // is this even necessary since getline() already consumes spaces and new lines?
        getline(cin, name);
    }
}
```

Because the `name` variable is of `string` type, shouldn't the `cin` object fail when it receives a number? How can I validate it and make sure it prompts for input again when a number is entered? Also, out of curiosity since I'm asking already, if the user enters something like: Scarlett9356, what would be a good way to re-prompt for good input? Thank you.

Comment: you can read "1234" from an input stream as either a number or a string: it's just a string of characters

Comment: The real difficult thing here is the big picture. What *is* a valid name for a person? It's much more complex than one might think: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ Of course, for a toy program, it's usually sufficient to make sure it only contains Aa-Zz and spaces.

Comment: Great read, thanks for sharing! @ChristianHackl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could validate that there are no numbers in your string by doing this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool validName(string name)
{
    if(name.length() == 0)
        return false; // `name` cannot be empty

    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
        if(name[i] >= '0' && name[i] <= '9') 
            return false; // There is a number in `name`

    return true; // `name` is valid
}

int main()
{
    string name = "";

    cout << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    while (!validName(name))
    {
        cout << "Numbers are not allowed, input name again: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); // is this even necessary since getline() already consumes spaces and new lines?
        getline(cin, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks good to me. When I run it though, pressing enter once will jump to the next line, and pressing enter again will actually stop the program. I commented out the `cin.ignore()` line and that fixed the first part of that issue, but now just pressing enter will stop the program. Could it be because the `for` loop needs some value to check if `i < name.length()` and pressing enter will mess it up?

Comment: @Blueshift: I've edited the `validName` function to reflect that new requirement! ;-) You can add more conditions to that function!

Answer (score 1):

> Because the name variable is of string type, shouldn't the cin object fail when it receives a number?

No. Input that consists of digits is valid as string also.

You'll need to use a different strategy for making that an invalid input.

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
bool is_valid_input(std::string const& name)
{
   bool is_valid = true;
   // Figure out the logic for deciding when the input is not valid.

   // ...

   if (!is_valid )
   {
      cout << "Numbers are not allowed, input name again: ";
   }

   return is_valid;
}

int main()
{
    string name = "";

    do
    {
       cout << "Enter name: ";
       getline(cin, name);
    }
    while ( !is_valid_input(name) );
}
```

Comment: Got it, thank you. Care to post some example code or elaborate more on your response?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit your input to only taking in string without a number in it then you can use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)

```
std::string name = "";

std::cout << "Enter name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);

while (std::any_of(name.begin(), name.end(), [](char ch) { return std::isdigit(ch); }))
{
    std::cout << "Numbers are not allowed, input name again: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
}
```